inotifywait --include doesn't fire for files in newly created directories. Bug (in inotifywait) or PEBKAC?
I want to run inotifywait to watch for all CREATEs of .txt files (recursively) under, let's say, the current directory. I run the following:
inotifywait -mr --event create --format '%e %w %f' --include '\.txt$' .

In another shell (from the same directory), I run the following:
touch 1.txt # inotifywait prints "CREATE ./ 1.txt" - all good.
mkdir mydir # inotifywait prints nothing - all good.
cd mydir    # inotifywait prints nothing - all good.
touch 1.txt # inotifywait prints nothing - NOT GOOD. I should have seen a "CREATE" message.

So despite me including the -r option (for which man inotifywait clearly states "Newly created subdirectories will also be watched."), my newly created subdirectory is clearly not being watched.
Is this:

a bug in inotifywait?
an error in my --include regex?
something else?

(FWIW, I'm running Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) and inotify-tools v3.22.6.0-4.)

mkdir dir.txt and then touch dir.txt/file.txt works. I'd suggest you've found a bug

Also, it works for directories not ending in .txt that existed before inotifywait is started.  Certainly a bug.

As another information point, it also works correctly if you omit the --include criterion. (But then you'd need to filter the output yourself.)

It's been a little while but there was a know bug using recursive where it would miss events that were done right after a new directory was created.   Had to to with the way a subtask is started for the new dir and at the time the author said it might not be fixable.  It go worse with the number of dir's under the top directory.   Try waiting a minute or two after mkdir before doing the touch.

I've reported this: https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/issues/224
